# jQuery addClass targeting correct element - but only applying class sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

For context - I'm currently working on a very basic Rails app which is designed to spit out HTML templates based on parameters entered into a form. However, I'm currently running into a *really* strange problem. I am using Bootstrap 3, and have a navigation which includes a dropdown submenu - because Bootstrap removed this feature from Bootstrap 3, I've had to borrow code from [here](http://www.bootply.com/92442#) to get it working.

In JSFiddle it works great, so there's no point in creating one; indeed, on my [static info page](http://guarded-ocean-8516.herokuapp.com/pages/info) it works great. On [every other page](http://guarded-ocean-8516.herokuapp.com/tab1s), it works about 10% of the time, usually directly after a refresh, and the rest of the time does not respond. I've checked out what's going on in Firebug and the correct element is being targeted (which Firebug shows by highlighting it in yellow) but is not always having the 'open' class added to it.

I am utterly baffled. Is this a Bootstrap thing? A Rails thing? Why is it *sometimes* working?!

EDIT - this is the jQuery in question. Really really basic.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use a non-minified js file on your site? It's much easier to troubleshoot that way.

Comment: Are you choosing elements via ID, and there's more than one element with that ID on the page?  jquery will behave unpredictably in this circumstance.

Comment: I can unminify the JS as soon as I figure out how to do so in Rails...!

Comment: I can reproduce the problem consistently now: Upon navigation by clicking on a navbar link, the navbar does not work until you click on a link again. Then it does work. Sort of a toggle between working and not working.

Comment: That's still incredibly weird but not as weird as random, I guess? The Javascript should be unminified now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this may take several tries since I can't test the changes.

`$('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]')` is a jquery selector that selects `[data-toggle=dropdown]` elements that are children of `ul` elements with the class `dropdown-menu` .

This ends up selecting nothing since there are no `ul` elements with the class `dropdown-menu`.

I think you want the following:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle[data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    //alert('clicked');
    //console.log('clicked');
});
```

Notice:
- no `<ul>` tag. You could use an `<a>` tag but it's unnecessary.
- no space between the class and the `[data-toggle]` since they are the same element.

To test it, you can uncomment either the alert or consolelog lines. If it's working, it should alert you once per click that changes the menu state.

**Testing Selectors**
Something you might find useful is to play around with jquery selectors in your browser's console. Open the console and send commands like `$('.dropdow-toggle')`. It will display all the elements that that selector selects. You can root out a lot of problems this way.